# Is this the right way to set custom font?

Tags: html, css, github-pages, hugo

I have a font in

> /static/font/input_regular.ttf

that i want to use for `code` tags, and i have this in my **styles.css**:

```html
@font-face {
  font-family: "Input_reg";
  src: url("/font/input_regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

pre, code {
  font-family: "Input_reg", monospace;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

The rest of the site is using *Source Code Pro* font.
Problem is, it doesn’t work, and never loads this new font, instead it just uses Source Code Pro, like the rest of the page. what am i doing wrong here?
If it matters, the site is using hugo, and is hosted on github pages.

Comment: More or less, you can use a webfont generator, such as: https://transfonter.org/, this will generate the correct font face css for you.

Comment: If you have an answer then post it in the answer section and mark it as correct in 2 days

Answer (score 0):

To serve Deepest Possible Browser Support.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Input_reg';
  src: url('/static/font/input_regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('/static/font/input_regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('/static/font/input_regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('/static/font/input_regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('/static/font/input_regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('/static/font/input_regular.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

pre, code {
  font-family: "Input_reg", monospace;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

Comment: his problem doesn't seem to be browsersupport - he is already using Source Code Pro, so I guess it's a path problem. So if it isnt working, as mentioned in my first answer: try loading the page while having F12 - nework tab on - look if th efonbt is loading correctly or if you get an 404 on the font. if it does give a 404, right click -  copy - url and then look where it tries to load from.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "input_reg";
  src: url("font/input_regular.ttf");
}
```

without the trailing / in the url. Also you dont need to specify thats a trueType and having all lowercase is **always** a good idea for nearly anything in the internet :-)
If that doesnt help, hit F12 in your browser, reload the page und look what URL the font is loaded from - it's probably wrong.